# Image of a line of pixels

Tags: visual, steganography

[image: small image; made of different pixels]

The puzzle is the image but the body requires thirty characters to be posted so ignore this.

Comment: Hexed Halloween.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The image

> Is made up of 33 pixels of different colours. Zooming in a bit:
>
>  [image]

Now

> If we extract the hex value of each colour, and convert it into ASCII we get the following:
>
> `776879, 206469, 642079, 6F7520, 737065, 6E6420, 69732A, 206D75, 636820, 74696D, 652064, 65636F, 64696E, 672074, 686973, 207374, 72696E, 673F20, 69276D, 206C69, 6B6520, 67656E, 75696E, 656C79, 20776F, 727269, 656420, 61626F, 757420, 796F75, 206C6F, 280000`
>
>  =
>
> `'why', ' di', 'd y', 'ou ', 'spe', 'nd ', '*th', 'is*', ' mu', 'ch ', 'tim', 'e d', 'eco', 'din', 'g t', 'his', ' st', 'rin', 'g? ', 'i'm', ' li', 'ke ', 'gen', 'uin', 'ely', ' wo', 'rri', 'ed ', 'abo', 'ut ', 'you', ' lo', '(  '`

Giving the string:

> 'Why did you spend *this* much time decoding this string? I'm like genuinely worried about you lol'

Appreciate the concern :P

Comment: Makes me wonder just how much effort went into creating this puzzle. :o)

Comment: @DanielMathias effort much better spent doing my AP homework (also i did it manually so thats fun)

Comment: @violetorigin No worries then.